# Get array element by its begin/end date in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to know a nice way to check which element in an array is the leading one (has priority) by its begin/end date.

For example, here is the array:

```
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 16
        [begin_date] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2016-01-01
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )
        [end_date] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2016-11-30
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )
    )

    [1] => Array
    (  
        [ID] => 33
        [begin_date] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2015-01-04
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )
        [end_date] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2016-02-29
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )
    )
)
```

In this case the second element has priority. Because its begin_date is earlier than the begin_date of the first element. And, its end_date is still in the future.

Conditions:

- If the begin_date is in the future, it cannot be the leading element
- If the end_date has expired (if today > end_date), the leading
  element must be the one with the latest end_date

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe [uasort](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.uasort.php) might help you

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Can you refine your second condition? If an end_date is expired, you want to get the element with the latest end_date overall or just from the expired ones?

Comment: Either `usort` all elements so they're in your preferred order, or `array_reduce` (or just loop) to find the "highest" one, whichever is more appropriate. Do you have problems expressing the business logic of the comparison? Or do you have problems with sorting an array?

Comment: @TobiasXy the latest end_date overall (if all end_date's are expired).

Comment: @KaloyanDoichinov I tried just a few basic conditions, like I described. But stopped because I knew it would end in many if else. So I ask to know if maybe one of you know an elegant way to do this.

Comment: @deceze the business logic of the comparison.

Comment: Then you would first have to clarify the business logic *in words*. Currently it's very wishy washy and incomplete.

Answer (score -1):

```
 uasort($memberArray,function($a,$b){
            $c = $a['begin_date']['date'] -  $b['begin_date']['date';
            $c .= $a['overall']['PD'] -  $b['overall']['PD'];
            $c .= $a['overall']['PF'] -  $b['overall']['PF'];
            $c .= $a['overall']['W'] -  $b['overall']['W'];
            $c .= $a['overall']['MP'] -  $b['overall']['MP'];
            return $c;
        });
```

Comment: `begin_date` is a \DateTime object and not an array and doesn't to my knowledge implement the ArrayAccess interface. so you can't navigate it like an array